# Difference between { actions: "" } and { entry: "" } in xstate?

Tags: state, state-management, xstate

It seems to me that you can fire an action in one of the following ways:

**Explicitly**

```js
{
  ...
  states: {
    foo: {
      on: {
        BAR: {
          actions: "performSomeAction",   
          target: "bar",
        },
      },
    },
    bar: {},
  },
  ...
}
```

**Implicitly with "entry"**

```
{
  ...
  states: {
    foo: {
      on: {
        BAR: "bar",
      }
    },
    bar: {
      entry: "performSomeAction",
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

In what circumstances would you choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Kourshid (creator of xstate) [answered](https://spectrum.chat/statecharts/general/difference-between-actions-and-entry-in-xstate~2b2482cf-4599-4bd6-9ac1-1cff64879eaa) this on Spectrum:

> They mean different things.
>
> - Transition actions mean "execute this action only on this transition"
> - Entry/exit actions mean "execute this action on any transition that enters/exits this state"